# How to get a certain information from xml file with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a xml file with nodes like this:

```
<n n="GUID" t="folder">   
   <a n="path" v="/abc/QWERTY/ghi" /> 
<n n="GUID" t="folder">   
   <a n="path" v="/abc/def/ghi" />
```

I need to get GUIDs from the first node.

And I am getting it with this script:

```
$Files_xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content "C:\Files.xml")
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $Files_links = @()
select-xml -xpath "//n[@t='folder']" -xml $Files_xml |  foreach {$Files_links += $_.Node.Attributes.GetNamedItem('n').Value}
```

Now I need to get GUIDs, but only if in path node it does not have "QWERTY"

It must be easy, but I don't know how to change selection

Comment: How to select needed GUID if there is multiply child notes? Like:
`<n n="GUID" t="folder">   
   <a n="name" v="smthng" />
   <a n="path" v="/abc/QWERTY/ghi" /> 
</n>
<n n="GUID" t="folder">  
   <a n="name" v="smthng" /> 
   <a n="path" v="/abc/def/ghi" />
</n>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **?** which is the alias for **Where-Object**.

```
[xml]$Files_xml = @"
    <xml>
        <n n="GUID123" t="folder">   
            <a n="path" v="/abc/QWERTY/ghi" />
        </n>
        <n n="GUID321" t="folder">   
            <a n="path" v="/abc/def/ghi" />
        </n>
    </xml>
"@

$Files_links = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList
select-xml -xpath "//n[@t='folder']" -xml $Files_xml  | Where-object{$_.Node.ChildNodes.v -notlike "*/QWERTY/*"}  |  foreach {$Files_links.Add($_.Node.Attributes.GetNamedItem('n').Value) | out-null}
$Files_links
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it helped me. What if node with guid have many child notes? Like:
`<n n="GUID123" t="folder"> 
    <a n="name" v="smthng" /> 
    <a n="path" v="/abc/QWERTY/ghi" /> 
</n>` 
How to select child note with specific name?